# C# VB.net syntax conversion advice

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to implement sqldependency in my vb.net application as per:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/156991-using-sqldependency-to-monitor-sql-database-changes/

I'm having problems with the involking code, when a notification is recieved the application locks up with no errors. (When MyOnChanged is called via the deligate)

Have I made a mistake in my C# > VB.net conversion?

```
  Private Sub GetNames()
    Dim connectionString As String = "String..."
    ListView1.Items.Clear()

    SqlDependency.[Stop](connectionString)
    SqlDependency.Start(connectionString)

    Using cn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Using cmd As SqlCommand = cn.CreateCommand()
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [finish_time], [file_name] FROM dbo.[log_table];"

            cmd.Notification = Nothing

            Dim dep As New SqlDependency(cmd)

            AddHandler dep.OnChange, New OnChangeEventHandler(AddressOf MyOnChanged)

            cn.Open()

            Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                While dr.Read()

                    Dim ls As New ListViewItem(dr.Item("finish_time").ToString.Trim())
                    ls.SubItems.Add(dr.Item("file_name").ToString.Trim())
                    ListView1.Items.Add(ls)

                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub




Private Sub MyOnChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SqlNotificationEventArgs)
    If ListView1.InvokeRequired Then
        ListView1.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf GetNames))
    Else
        GetNames()
    End If
    Dim dep As SqlDependency = TryCast(sender, SqlDependency)
    AddHandler dep.OnChange, New OnChangeEventHandler(AddressOf MyOnChanged)
End Sub
```

Comment: One trick you could try is to code it in C#, get it compiling, then look at the code in .NET reflector (search the web for this tool).  This will allow you to take any .NET code, and view it in any other language, such as VB.Net.

Comment: Also, learning to use the debugger is extremely useful in a case like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Merlyn recommended, I used .NET reflector to work out the proper .net conversion:

```
Private Sub MyOnChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SqlNotificationEventArgs)
    If MyBase.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.LVFTPXfers.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf Me.GetNames))
    Else
        Me.GetNames()
    End If
    Dim dependency As SqlDependency = TryCast(sender, SqlDependency)
    RemoveHandler dependency.OnChange, New OnChangeEventHandler(AddressOf Me.MyOnChanged)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the code conversion tool in SharpDevelop for the Mono Project:

- [SharpDevelop Wiki](http://wiki.icsharpcode.net/(S(km4tuymexav12abtpdhgtb45))/History.aspx?Page=gsoc&Revision=83)

"... It includes features like ... **code conversion between C# and VB.NET** ..."

[image]
<sub>(source: [softpedia.com](http://www.softpedia.com/screenshots/SharpDevelop_5.png))</sub>